# the text doesn't break into a paragraph

Tags: css, whitespace

simply: why this happens?
when I have a text with no space , like a url link, the line continues outer the text area.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUSL5.png)

apparently this is what happens in similar situations, but how to prevent it? some times it really happens that a line is too long with no space inbetween the words.

Comment: Please add the code so we can reproduce your issue. An image is not suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your paragraph class or tag

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```